# iPhone code forUIImageViewControllerPickerSourceTypeCamera

Tags: iphone

```
- (IBAction)pickAndDecode:(id) sender {
  UIImagePickerControllerSourceType sourceType;
  int i = [sender tag];

  switch (i) {
    case 0: sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera; break;
    case 1: sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum; break;
    case 2: sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary; break;
    default: sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
  }
  [self pickAndDecodeFromSource:sourceType];
}

- (void) updateToolbar {
  self.cameraBarItem.enabled = [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
  self.savedPhotosBarItem.enabled = [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum];
  self.libraryBarItem.enabled = [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
  self.archiveBarItem.enabled = true;
  self.actionBarItem.enabled = (self.result != nil) && ([self.result actions] != nil) && ([self.result actions].count > 0);
}

- (void)pickAndDecodeFromSource:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType) sourceType {
  [self reset];

  // Create the Image Picker
  if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:sourceType]) {
    UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.sourceType = sourceType;
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsImageEditing = YES; // [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"allowEditing"];

    // Picker is displayed asynchronously.
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
  } else {
    NSLog(@"Attempted to pick an image with illegal source type '%d'", sourceType);
  }
}
```

Where I Put this line in my above codes;
[picker setShowsCameraControls:FALSE];

please help me so that i can change the real view of iPhone camera according to my view which i have designed

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to put it where you create and setup your image picker, i.e. in `pickAndDecodeFromSource` method?